# How to change parent component from nested child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The situation is like this. There is an array of object called tableData storing table rows, which is now stored in vuex

The component structure is like this:

Parent (page) -> child 1 (tableLayout)-> child 2 (tableBody)-> child 3 (row)

In child 3, there is a delete function to remove an index in tableData.

The parent needs to update its data (selectedRow) which will be passed to another unrelated child component if the id of the row deleted is the selectedRow Id.

Currently I am using watch to watch tableData to react to the change in parent component. However, the watch function will always loop over tableData to find if selectedRow still exist whenever tableData is updated, which is quite undesirable when the array is huge.

I thought of using emit but it will have to go through 2 components to reach the parent, making the code hard to manage

I also thought of using bus, but its not a good practice as well.

Can anyone give me any suggestion on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the selectedRow in vuex then in child3 update selectedRow in your vuex store

Answer (score 1):

Since you have stored the tableData in vuex... you can achieve this using mutation

From your child2 component you can just call a mutation to remove the particular index from tableData

for example

```
this.$store.commit('removeIndex', payload) // where removeIndex is a mutation handler and payload is the index value sent as argument
```

Comment: If you could share a vuex code then I can update my answer with respect to your code itself

Comment: The index is removed. It is that I have to assign another value to a variable called selectedRow (a local state in parent component) if the row removed is the one I am selecting. I am trying to find the optimal way for the deeply nested child component to notify the root parent about the change.

Comment: ah then you can have a state called 'selectedRow' in vuex inside which you can store that particular value before deletion.  And then in your parent component..you can access the state using ...mapState(['selectedRow']) which is by nature reactive

Comment: It seems to be the best option in this case. I was worried about overusing vuex because I thought selectedRow should be a local data but I guess there's no better choice. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer